# Auto Sync wordpress post with blogger.com blogspot

Tags: wordpress, seo, blogger, blogspot

I want to sync my wordpress blog post with blogspot.com blog. at least the post title and the wordpress post link should be displayed on my blog.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) service.

You can do a trigger '**When a new post on my wp blog**' and set the action '**Create a post on blogger**'

This recipe will do it: https://ifttt.com/recipes/31738

Comment: I need some plugin that can do this. Earlier I was using ping.fm

Answer (score 1):

I will never keep same copy of my content on different blog by considering recent algorithm updates rolled out by Google named (panda and penguin). It is just waste of time and may harm your website too.

Better to post unique article as quality matter a lot as compare to quantity !

Comment: Yah you are right. But i just need the excerpt (post title and url) on the blogspot and the complete post remain on the wordpress website.

Comment: Sorry but may i know the motive behind doing this?

Comment: I don't know but for some reason my web page are ranked at 3 and 4th page of google search for the keywords it were on the first page. My seo techniques were not changed. So I think getting a blogspot and just sharing the Post title and the link could increase my traffic.

Comment: Frankly speaking, it wont help in improving ranks !! better you focus on quality content. Let me know if i can help you in anyway !

Comment: Thanks Sophie, The problem was due to Googlebot can't access my site. I have discussed with my hosting provider hopefully things would get better within a week.

Comment: humm...if you don't mind, share your website URL by msg. I may help you in getting your website crawled by search engines. Just check robots.txt as i don't think there is any role of your hosting providers.

Comment: No idea how to send msg through stackflow. The domain name is paktutorial.com but i am more concern with subdomain jobs.paktutorial and vu.paktutorial

Comment: Your website already crawled by Google !! check this https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fpaktutorial.com%2F&pws=0&gl=US

if you get answer of your query, plz accept the answer !!
You just need to work on quality content and quality backlinks.

Comment: Many Thanks Sophie for the help.